# java - Longest string in array containing vowel at start and the end

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to get the longest string in an array that starts and ends with a vowel. When I run my code the longest value is displayed after each loop, but it does not display the highest value for the variable **longest**.

```
class xJava
{
public static void firstlastVowel (String theString)
{
    int index;
    int longest=0;
    char x = theString.charAt(index=0);
    char y = theString.charAt(theString.length()-1);
    int z = theString.length()-1;

    if(x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u')
    {
        if(y == 'a' || y == 'e' || y == 'i' || y == 'o' || y == 'u')
        {
            System.out.println(theString + " starts and ends with a vowel");

            if(z > longest)
            {
                longest = z;
                System.out.println("longest string is "+longest+" characters!");
            }
        }


    }
}



public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int index;
    String value;

    String[] things = {"abba", "orlando", "academia", "ape"};


    for(String thing : things)
    {
        firstlastVowel(thing);
    }

}

}
```

how can I get the variable longest to only contain the length of the longest string?

output is :

```
 abba starts and ends with a vowel
 longest string is 3 characters!
 orlando starts and ends with a vowel
 longest string is 6 characters!
 academia starts and ends with a vowel
 longest string is 7 characters!
 ape starts and ends with a vowel
 longest string is 2 characters!
```

Comment: can you add the output you get?

Comment: Please consider that firstlastVowel will be called 4 times, once for each word in your String array. Longest is set to 0 each time firstlastVowel is called and it's always going to be equal to that string.

Comment: It is best to give your method the Array in parameter and loop in the method then return the longest

Comment: Z = theString.length() is better. You miss a character each time otherwise

Comment: And what is supposed to happen when two or more strings obey both criteria and have an equal length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem -

Your `longest` variable is method scoped in `firstlastVowel` and is reset to zero every time you make a call to `firstlastVowel` method.

Initialize it in the `main` method and pass it as a parameter to `firstlastVowel` along with the `thing` and use `Integer` type instead of `int` in order to keep the reference between the multiple passes of this variable to the `firstlastVowel` method.

Comment: how would I go about passing the **longest** variable into the firstlastVowel method?

Comment: Ok, here are the steps - 1.) declare and initialize the longest variable in main method - `Integer longest = 0;` 2.) delete the declaration line from firstlastVowel method i.e. delete - `int longest = 0;` 3.) change `public static void firstlastVowel (String theString)` to `public static void firstlastVowel (String theString, Integer longest)` in third line of your class xJava

Comment: also 4.) Change the line in `main` method where you are making a call to `firstlastVowel` from `firstlastVowel(thing);` to `firstlastVowel(thing, longest);`

Answer (score 2):

Gah, I should know better than to post this:

```
  String[] things = { "aa", "orrro", "academia", "ape" };
  int longest = Arrays.stream(things)
      .filter(s -> s.matches("^[aeiouy].*[aeiouy]$"))
      .map(String::length)
      .reduce(0, Math::max);
  System.out.println("longest string is " + longest + " characters!");
```

Why and how that works is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Ha! I like that Java 8+ solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simple example of what you need:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] things = {"abba", "orlando", "academia", "ape", "nebuchadnezzar", "academi","academian"};
    String longestWord = getLongestVowelWord(things);
    System.out.println("The longest vowel word is: " + longestWord);
}

/**
 * Method returning the String which starts and ends with a vowel and is the longest
 * within the Strings given as an array in this method's parameter
 * @param words String array containing words to be examined by the method
 * @return String object which starts and ends with a vowel and is the longest from
 * the words given as a String array
 */
private static String getLongestVowelWord(String[] words){
    String longestWord = "";
    for(String word : words){
        if(longestWord.length() < getVowelWordLength(word)){
            longestWord = word;
        }
    }
    return longestWord;
}

/**
 * Method check if word starts and ends with a vowel
 * and returning it's length it case it matches the pattern
 * @param word a word whose length is being checked on condition that it starts and ends with a vowel
 * @return if word starts and ends with a vowel, returns it's lenght. Returns -1 otherwise.
 */
private static Integer getVowelWordLength(String word){
    // check if first and last char of the word is a vowel
    // toLowerCase() is used for simplicity of isVowel(char c) method - it does not have to check the upper case chars
    if(isVowel(word.toLowerCase().charAt(0)) 
                && isVowel(word.toLowerCase().charAt(word.length()-1)))
        return word.length();
    else
        return -1;
}

/**
 * Method checking if given char is a vowel
 * @param c char being checked for being a vowel
 * @return <code>true</code> if given char is a vowel, <code>false</code> otherwise
 */
private static boolean isVowel(char c){
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}
```